# how to access an instance of an controller

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember application with a viewer template, viewer controller and a list of items that represents the model for the viewer template. 
The application contains two main functionality: view one single item or compare two or more items.
For single view it is quite simple: I have only one instance of viewer controller for that I changed the model when the user wants to see another item.
For multiple views I have a problem: I have multiple instances of the same viewer controllers and for some actions I need the instance to send the action to the viewer controller from the route. For single view, I get the instance of the controller with controllerFor('name of it') but when there are multiple instances I do not know how to access a specific controller instance.

For multiple view, the user needs to select with the mouse the active item. Internally the item from the model has an selected property that is true only when the user clicks it.

One idea, probably not the good one, will be to keep the controller instance on each item in the model. In this way I will look for the selected item and from that item I will took the controller instance. Another idea will be to keep on the route the instance of the viewer controller that is selected.

Do you know what is the best method to access with EmberJS a specific instance of a controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have the parent controller be an `ArrayController` with the `itemController` property set to your current viewer controller. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html

You can then render them with an `{{#each}}` in your template and even specify a view if you need to.

Comment: This is exactly the situation that I have: an array controller that is rendered in template with a {{each}} in a UL list. But for some actions I need the correct instance of the itemController in the route and I don't know how to retrieve it.

Comment: you can use `arrayController.findBy('id', id);` to get a specific controller from it @shareit